# Error with mutate() when using characters in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working with a dataset looking like this:

```
test_accuracy <- data.frame(observed = c("Feeding/Moving", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving"),
                            predicted = c("Standing", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding"))
```

I'm trying to transform my data by replacing some characters in the column `predicted`, such as:

1) replace `Feeding/Moving` for `Standing`

2) replace `Standing` for `Moving/Feeding`

3) replace `Moving/Feeding` for `Feeding/Moving`

I've tried to apply this transformation in a compact way using the code below, and got the following errors:

```
> test_accuracy<-test_accuracy %>%
+ mutate(predicted = case_when(predicted == 'Feeding/Moving' ~ 'Standing',
+                                predicted == 'Standing' ~ 'Moving/Feeding',
+                                predicted == 'Moving/Feeding' ~ 'Feeding/Moving',
+                                TRUE ~ predicted)) %>%
+ 
+ 
+ head(test_accuracy)
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: must be type character, not integer
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace.
```

However, when trying to rectify by setting type to `character`, I get the opposite error message:

```
> test_accuracy<-as.character(test_accuracy)
> test_accuracy<-test_accuracy %>%
+ mutate(predicted = case_when(predicted == 'Feeding/Moving' ~ 'Standing',
+                                predicted == 'Standing' ~ 'Moving/Feeding',
+                                predicted == 'Moving/Feeding' ~ 'Feeding/Moving',
+                                TRUE ~ predicted)) %>%
+ 
+ 
+ head(test_accuracy)
Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Any idea of how I can achieve the desired transformation described above with this dataset? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You may want to consider creating a second dataset with columns `predicted` and `new_calc` or something like that and join.

Comment: I tried the above and was not able to reproduce the error.

Comment: @TomHaddow You had the right answer?

Comment: Yup it worked as intended. I assume from the pipe operator after the case_when that this is taken from a larger chunk of code?

Comment: In the case at the bottom where you get the error, you're calling `mutate` on `test_accuracy`, which seems to be a character vector. `dplyr` functions such as `mutate` are intended to be called on data frames

Comment: I think @Camille has it. Instead of `test_accuracy<-as.character(test_accuracy)` do `test_accuracy$predicted <- as.character(test_accuracy$predicted)` (probably worth double checking test_accuracy is in fact a data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

When I face these kind of problems with a few categories, I use nested `ifelse()` functions to incorporate it in a `mutate()` function. My suggestion is the following:

```
df <- data.frame(observed = c("Feeding/Moving", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving"),
                 predicted = c("Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Moving/Feeding"))

new_df <- df %>% 
  mutate(new_observed = ifelse(observed == "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", 
         ifelse(observed == "Moving/Feeding", "Feeding/Moving", "Standing")),
         new_predicted = ifelse(predicted == "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", 
         ifelse(predicted == "Moving/Feeding", "Feeding/Moving", "Standing")))
```

Notice that the second `ifelse()` function is placed as the third argument in the first `ifelse()` function to make a new condition if the first condition is not `True`. The resulting output is this (forgive me if I misunderstood the replacing rules above):

```
> new_df
        observed      predicted   new_observed  new_predicted
1 Feeding/Moving       Standing       Standing Moving/Feeding
2 Moving/Feeding       Standing Feeding/Moving Moving/Feeding
3 Moving/Feeding       Standing Feeding/Moving Moving/Feeding
4 Moving/Feeding       Standing Feeding/Moving Moving/Feeding
5 Feeding/Moving       Standing       Standing Moving/Feeding
6 Feeding/Moving Moving/Feeding       Standing Feeding/Moving
```

Comment: The `case_when()` function (https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) can be easier to read and a little more efficient when comparing a vector against multiple conditions.